# Android screenshot from code. Got it but not perfect

Tags: android, android-layout, screenshot, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to take a screenshot in code in Android. Actually the screenshot is the bitmap of the main RelativeLayout. The screenshot is taken but the content appears wrong, the fill_parent, etc tags are not respected and the image appears in the top left and with the original size.

Please anyone, help.

Thanks

This is my code :

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        // this is the important code :)
        // Without it the view will have a
        // dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will
        // be null
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        //v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); //

        if (bm != null) {
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, "screentest.jpg");
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

                Log.e("ImagePath", "Image Path : "
                        + MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                file.getName(), file.getName()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And this is the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/backImage" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />

<com.calendarView.CalendarView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

@ns476

Comment: Is the problem(ImageView size) related to making a screenshot? I mean, what does it look like in the emulator? Is it the correct size then?

Comment: could you show the screen how's exactly it display and hows you getting image?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the screen size in `makeMeasureSpec`

```
...
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, size.x),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, size.y));
...
```

Also try setting the [setDrawingCacheQuality](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheQuality%28int%29) to high, so that it returns a higher resolution bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace the

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

v.buildDrawingCache(true);

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());

v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

with

```
Bitmap bitmap;

View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

View v1 = root.getRootView();

v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());

root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing this during creation. Don't!

use a postDelayed(Runnable, int) to execute the `Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());` after the view is drawn.

also, remove the v.measure() and v.layout()
those are methods for the ViewGroup to be calling.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines:

```
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
//v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.layout);
     ll .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();`

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This works good for me:

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.myElementForScreenshoot);
View screenshot = content; // or content.getRootView() for fullscreen
screenshot.refreshDrawableState();
screenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = screenshot.getDrawingCache();
```

After this you can process or save bitmap. Hope it helped. Cheers