# How to take screen shot programatically in Android?

Tags: android, screenshot

How can I take screenshot of selected area of phone-screen not by any program, but from code.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: Do the same as a normal screenshot, but remove the user input and "just do it".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056000/android-screenshot-from-code-got-it-but-not-perfect

Your answer is on the page above.

Comment: Take a look here, hope it helps :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: Hello i want to take screen shot of google map with markers on it but i am getting only blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you need to access use something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
```